# A Probability Problem About Seating Arrangements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm having trouble with a probability question. It goes, "a class room has three rows of 4 seats. These 12 seats are randomly assigned to 4 male students and 5 female students. a)What is the probability that no female student sits in the front row?"

What I've tried to do is divide 8 choose 5 by 12 choose 9. But that isn't the answer. Apparently the answer is 7/99 and I've got no idea how the book got there.

Can someone please explain to me how to do it? Can you not only show me the solution, but also explain to me, how you got there? Thanks.

Comment: For part (a) there is no reference to the men... so we may safely ignore their presence.  Ignoring order, how many ways can seats be occupied by the women if we don't care about whether or not there are any in the front row?  How many ways can seats be occupied by the women if we want to make sure none sit in the front row?  [Binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) will be used.  There are 12 seats total and we want to *choose* 5 of them... or there are 8 non-front-row seats available and we want to *choose* 5 of them...

Comment: a tricky part is that there are three empty seats to account for

Comment: @DevashishKaushik I've edited the question to show what I've done.

Comment: I see, and as a result you have also found an answer that works for you, that's the way to go :D   (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is:$$\frac{\binom85\binom40}{\binom{12}5}=\frac{\binom85}{\binom{12}5}$$

You only have to focus on females and this is the probability that $5$ chairs are selected for them that do not belong to the front row.

Comment: Shouldn't it be out of 12 choose 9 ways though? Because that's the total amount of possibilities of seats! I don't really get why you can limit total possibilities to just females.

Comment: @EthanChan when approaching a probability question, you may choose to have your sample space as complicated or as simple as you like, so long as calculations within that sample space are convenient (*e.g., equiprobable sample spaces are generally superior choices*) and so long as the event you wish to calculate the probability of can be described as a subset of your sample space.  We could have described our sample space here as the set of ordered $9$-tuples keeping track of who sits where.  We could have chosen many other sample spaces to describe the problem.

Comment: @EthanChan Consider a problem where I flip a coin, I roll a die, and I purchase a lottery ticket.  I ask the question of whether or not the coin landed heads.  I certainly could have treated my sample space as the set of all possible $3$-tuples where the first entry is the result of the coin flip, the second the result of the die toss, and the third as the lottery ticket number chosen.  If I only wanted information about the coinflip, the rest is unnecessary and irrelevant.

Comment: The same is true here.  The only relevant information to us is information about *where* the *women* collectively are sitting (*the order in which they sit is even irrelevant*).  If you wanted to have your sample space to include information about where the men sit, that is fine, I would have used $\binom{12}{5}\binom{7}{4}$ or $\binom{12}{9}\binom{9}{4}$ however, as it is still relevant which of the nine seats are occupied by women.  The point to take away from all of this is that simpler sample spaces often simplify calculations considerably.

Comment: Thanks  for the detailed response!